# How to do nested dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

As a beginner to Swift I'm struggling with even the simplest things :( I've tried in so many ways to create a dictionary within a dictionary but it always fails.

The reason is a I want to fill a table with 10 items. Each item has a title, url, pageviews and unique users. String, string, int, int. I want to be able to both read the data and fill the tablecell by using IndexPath.row and I want to be able to update the data every 5th second based on input from a api with json content.

I was trying in Playground and ended up with:

```
var topArticleDetails:[String:AnyObject] = ["title":"","url":"","uniqueUsers":0,"events":0]
var topArticles:[Int:NSDictionary] = [0:topArticleDetails]

topArticleDetails["title"] = "Varden - Nyheter"
topArticleDetails["url"] = "http://www.varden.no/nyheter"
topArticleDetails["uniqueUsers"] = 50
topArticleDetails["events"] = 100

topArticles[1] = topArticleDetails
```

and it seems to work fine, but when I add this to my ViewController I'm getting the error **Instance member 'topArticleDetails' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'**

Close but no cigar..

How can I solve this? Maybe there is a better way than the one I'm trying now. At the moment it's kinda working but instead of having a nested dictionary I've ended up with four seperate arrays like this:

```
var topArticlesTitle = [String]()
var topArticlesURL = [String]()
var topArticlesEvents = [Int]()
var topArticlesUniqueUsers = [Int]()
```

and I'm pretty sure there must be a better way.

**>> UPDATE <<**

In addition to the solutions provided below I found another one. It's so simple I'm ashamed but I guess it's a part of learning both Swift and OOP at the same time. If I removed the data I tried to enter into the variables when declaring them and just kept them empty it worked like a charm.

```
var topArticleDetails = [String:AnyObject]()
var topArticles = [Int:NSDictionary]()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see how/where you are using this with your view controller.

Comment: Thank you @CaseyFleser but I guess it's ok now as I got help figuring it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a dictionary inside a dictionary, you can use and `struct` array, for example:

```
struct Article {
    var title: String?
    var url: String?
    var: events: Int?
    var uniqueUsers: Int?
}

var topArticles = [Article]()
```

It is more easy to mantain than the dictionary inside dictionary because it will be easy to change your model.

Comment: Man, I've noticed a lot of people abusing arrays, tuples and dictionaries when they really should be using structs.

Comment: Struct it is! I've not reached that chapter yet :) But thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about nested Dictionaries (I would go with pableiros's answer though for not abusing dictionaries, structs work better) you can declare them like this:

```
var test = [Int: [String: AnyObject]]()
```

To convert JSON, you can use the `NSJSONSerialization` class:

```
try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(your_encoded_json, options: []) as! [Int: [String: AnyObject]]
```